# Get autocompleted value from input in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in my view:

```html
<label for="txtFrom">Pickup Location</label>
<input type="text" id="pickup" placeholder="Address, aiport, train station, hotel..." ng-model="pickup">
<label for="txtDestination">Destination</label>
<input type="text" id="destination" placeholder="Address, aiport, train station, hotel..." ng-model="destination">
<input class="btn btn-success" name="calcPrice" id="calcPrice" type="submit" value="Calculate Price" ng-click="calcPrice()">
```

I am using google maps api for places to autocomplete the input boxes, so if a user starts typing "Lo", he will get a list of places that starts with "Lo" and for example he chooses London.

The problem is in my controller I am not getting the whole autocompleted value. I am only getting what the user initially entered, in this case "Lo".

Here is my controller:

```js
app.controller('BookingsCtrl', function($scope, BookingsService) {
  $scope.pickup = "";
  $scope.destination = "";
  $scope.syncNotification = "";

  $scope.calcPrice = function() {
    console.log($scope.pickup);

    BookingsService.save({
      pickup: $scope.pickup,
      destination: $scope.destination
    }, function(response) {
      console.log(response.message);
    });
  };
});
```

EDIT:
Here is also a snippet of the JS:

```
var pickup = document.getElementById('pickup');

var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'ee'
    }
};

var autocompletePickup = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pickup, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocompletePickup, 'place_changed', function () {

    var place = autocompletePickup.getPlace();
    pickup.innerHtml =  place.formatted_address;
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var long = place.geometry.location.lng();

});
```

EDIT 2 : Added service

```
app.service('BookingsService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:3000/', {});
});
```

EDIT 3 : Template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDt1Y30OssBToIzSCOr3g5IkN3c0D75XVE&libraries=places"
     ></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='strelsau_client'>
  <div class="site-wrapper">
     <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
        <div class="cover-container">
           <div class="masthead clearfix">
              <div class="inner">
                 <img class="masthead-brand" src="../assets/img/logo.png">
                 <nav>
                    <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </nav>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div ng-view>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/bookings_controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/bookings_service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include the piece of your service.

Comment: @alphapilgrim updated post to include service

Comment: does the request fire successfully?

Comment: Yes request is firing successfully. It's just that I am getting only what the user has typed as parameters from the input

Comment: Sounds like a job for [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). You could then debouce the input and capture entire binding.

Comment: I've updated the post with the template

Comment: @alphapilgrim I've tried ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default',debounce: 200 }" but it does not seem to make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `pickup` input element is not getting updated once the place is resolved.

The problem with this function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocompletePickup, 'place_changed', function () {

    var place = autocompletePickup.getPlace();
    pickup.innerHtml =  place.formatted_address; //invalid
    //...
});
```

For setting input field value should be used `value` property.

Anyway, given the example, try to replace it with:

```
(function (scope) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocompletePickup, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = autocompletePickup.getPlace();
                scope.pickup = place.formatted_address;
            });
        })($scope);
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('BookingsCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.pickup = "";
        $scope.destination = "";
        $scope.syncNotification = "";

        var pickup = document.getElementById('pickup');

        var options = {
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'ee'
            }
        };
        var autocompletePickup = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pickup, options);

        (function (scope) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocompletePickup, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = autocompletePickup.getPlace();
                scope.pickup = place.formatted_address;
            });
        })($scope);

        $scope.calcPrice = function () {
            console.log($scope.pickup);
            alert($scope.pickup);

            /*BookingsService.save({
                pickup: $scope.pickup,
                destination: $scope.destination
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.message);
            });*/
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BookingsCtrl" ng-cloak>
        <label for="txtFrom">Pickup Location</label>
        <input type="text" id="pickup" placeholder="Address, aiport, train station, hotel..." ng-model="pickup">
        <label for="txtDestination">Destination</label>
        <input type="text" id="destination" placeholder="Address, aiport, train station, hotel..." ng-model="destination">
        <input class="btn btn-success" name="calcPrice" id="calcPrice" type="submit" value="Calculate Price" ng-click="calcPrice()">
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems to work in the fiddle you provided. But I am getting this error at my place :  ReferenceError: $scope is not defined(…)

Comment: `$scope` is not accessible in context of  `place_changed` event, that is why you need to pass it (the same way as in the example i have provided)

Comment: I've used it the same way as you've provided and it is infact working correctly now! But I don't get why I am getting this error in the console.